# Iniciar função em uma tag específica com JavaScript puro (gridalicious)

Tags: javascript

Galera, gostaria de pedir a ajuda de vocês para solucionar esta dúvida que estou enfrentando.

Como seria o equivalente, em JavaScript puro, do seguinte código jQuery

```
    $(document).function();
```

Sendo mais específico, estou tentando reescrever este código abaixo.

```
    $(".grid-a-licious").gridalicious({ //parameters })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenho de responder a outra coisa primeiro:

Quando tens `$(".grid-a-licious").gridalicious({ //parameters })` podes separar isso em duas partes:

`$(".grid-a-licious")` é basicamente um seletor para ir buscar elementos do DOM, ou seja isso vai retornar uma array de  objetos jQuery com os elementos DOM que têm a classe `grid-a-licious`.

O `$` é uma função que o jQuery cria e é a base da API do jQuery.

Aí, a esses elementos, será corrido o método `.gridalicious()`. Isso implica que tens de ter o jQuery carregado e ainda um ficheiro à parte (plugin) com uma certa funcionalidade, neste caso o *gridalicious*. Este "plugin" foi adicionado ao protótipo do jQuery o que quer dizer que todos os objetos que o jQuery retorne passam a ter esse método. Isso pode ser feito com:

```
$.prototype.gridalicious = function(){ };
```

Ou seja, quando perguntas como escrever em JavaScript puro. Tirando o jQuery qye é uma biblioteca enorme, só esse plugin [tem 327 linhas de código](https://github.com/suprb/Grid-A-Licious/blob/master/jquery.grid-a-licious.js) e não dá para responder aqui acerca de como converter para JavaScript puro como deves compreender.

O que sugiro é procurares decrever melhor a funcionalidade que procuras, o que já testaste e colocares isso noutra pergunta. Provavelmente o CSS moderno já faz a maior parte da funcionalidade que precisas.

Comment: Entendi.
Mas, me corrija se eu estiver enganado:
    $(".grid-a-licious") 
Equivale à
    document.querySelector(".grid-a-licious");

Isto está correto?

Se sim, poderia eu fazer desta forma:
    document.querySelector(".grid-a-licious").gridalicious({}); ?

Comment: @Marlom nõ é assim tão simples. Terias de juntar esse método ao protótipo de elementos DOM, para além de que terias de converter todo o código do plugin...

Comment: Sou iniciante no JavaScript.
Olha, seguindo o que foi mencionado, se $(".grid-a-licious") equivale a document.querySelector(".grid-a-licious"), não funcionaria se eu iterar entre os elementos contidos dentro de ".grid-a-licious" e atribuir a cada um deles a função chamada?

Comment: Marlom não. Tens de carregar o jQuery e o plugin está feito em jQuery. Tens de converter tudo.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento Sergio.